# How can I refresh a VectorTile layer in OpenLayers without causing a visible flicker?

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I have an OpenLayers map with various Vector and VectorTile layers. Most of the VectorTile layers return reasonably static data, but one of them is updated by my application.

If after (through a separate API) adding or removing a feature from this layer, I call `.refresh()` on the source, all the features will disappear for several hundred milliseconds at least (while the new data is loaded), which I want to avoid. This is shown in the image below.

[image: Demonstration of the flicker that is seen when calling refresh on the source]

I have hacked together an approach of completely re-adding the layer and then removing the old one, but is there a better way?

If there was at least a convenient way to clone an existing layer and source, that would help the "workaround" approach to be more manageable.

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.